# remove UTF-8 char from end of a byte array

Tags: c, utf-8, arrays

I want to remove utf8 chars from end of a byte array in C 
I've tried the code below for removing the character , the code works fine for 1 or 2 byte characters but doesn't work for removing characters requiring more than 2 bytes of space...
I have 2 question : 
is there a better way to implement this and how can i fix the current code

```
if( ((int)bytearray[counter-6]) >= 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 && strlen(bytearray) >= 6 )
            for (i=0;i<6;i++)
                bytearray[--counter] = (char) 0;
        else if( ((int)bytearray[counter-5]) >= 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 && strlen(bytearray) >= 5 )
            for (i=0;i<5;i++)
                bytearray[--counter] = (char) 0;
        else if( ((int)bytearray[counter-4]) >= 128 + 64 + 32 + 16  && strlen(bytearray) >= 4  )
            for (i=0;i<4;i++)
                bytearray[--counter] = (char) 0;
        else if( ((int)bytearray[counter-3]) >= 128 + 64 + 32 && strlen(bytearray) >= 3   )
            for (i=0;i<3;i++)
                bytearray[--counter] = (char) 0;
        else if( ((int)bytearray[counter-2]) >= 128 + 64 && strlen(bytearray) >= 2 )
            for (i=0;i<2;i++)
                bytearray[--counter] = (char) 0;
        else
            bytearray[--counter] = (char) 0;
```

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: assumes chars more than 2 bytes as 2 byte chars , I think i didn't understand the bitmaps very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description , you could find that the beginning byte of each UTF-8 character is either `0xxxxxxx` or `11xxxxxx`. That is, the beginning byte is *never* `10xxxxxx`.

Thus, assume `bytearray` is of type `char*` or `char[]`, then you could write

```
for (counter = strlen(bytearray)-1; counter >= 0; --counter) {
    if ((bytearray[counter] & 0xC0) != 0x80) {
        // beginning byte of a character
        bytearray[counter] = '\0';
        break;
    }
    // consequent bytes. Clear and keep going.
    // Indeed this is optional since the first '\0' already terminates a C string
    bytearray[counter] = '\0';
}
```